# @ExposeResourceFor multiple resources

Tags: spring, rest, annotations, hateoas

I have a controller for which I want to provide hateoas links. The problem is that I have multiple return types in this controller: `User` and `UserDto`. My annotation tells that I expose only `User`, but I also want `UserDto`.

```
@RestController
@ExposesResourceFor(User.class)
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @GetMapping(value = "/othermodel")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource<UserDto>> getOtherUser(
        @PathVariable final String id) {

        Resource<UserDto> resource = new Resource<>(uService.getUser(id));
        resource.add(entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(UserDto.class, id));            
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Should I make another Controller for `UserDto`? Or there are annotation that I need to add to `UserDto` or maybe extend `ResourceSupport` to make this work? I tried a lot of combinations with these.

But I still get this error: "Cannot determine link for UserDto! No EntityLinks instance found supporting the domain type!"

I can add the link the following way, but I still want to use `EntityLinks`

```
resource.add(
    linkTo(methodOn(UsersController.class).getOtherUser(id)).withSelfRel()
);
```

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: no, I have removed hateoas.You can remove the @ExposesResourceFor annotaion and manually add the links you want on each endpoint